# LDAP proxy to ActiveDirectory not working

Tags: linux, active-directory, openldap

I installed openldap as a proxy to ActiveDirectory and it's working if I use a full DN.

The problem is that AD supports query with the following syntax but OpenLdap does not.

```
ldapsearch -v -H ldap://hostname 
           -x -b "OU=Users,OU=OU_Test,DC=TEST,DC=Local"
           -D "0980980@test.local"
           -w ******** sAMAccountName="0980980"
```

OpenLdap complains with the following error:

```
Invalid DN syntax (34)
```

Is it possible to configure OpenLdap to pass through this syntax ?

Answer (score 0):

meanwhile I found a quick and dirty solution with socat (in a loop in case of crash):

```
adhost=10.100.100.100

trap 'kill $(jobs -p)' EXIT; until socat TCP-LISTEN:389,fork TCP:$adhost:389 & wait; do
    echo "ldap proxy crashed with exit code $?. Respawning.." >&2
    sleep 1
done
```